# Can't get access to samba server

Tags: networking, server, samba, configuration

This is driving me insane. I just can't seem to get my ubuntu samba server to work.

These are some of my smb.conf settings.

```
workgroup = WORKGROUP    
map to guest = Bad User
wins support = Yes

[Cloud]
  path = /media/stephen/ExternalHDD/Cloud
  valid users = stephen
  read only = no
```

I'm able to login using the smbclient, but Windows keeps telling me my access is denied, even if I'm using the exact same credentials as with the smbclient.

What could the problem be?

Comment: Could it be possible, a missing slash in the beginning of the path to be a cause of this problem? :: `/`  `media/stephen/ExternalHDD/Cloud`

Comment: No, that was actually a typo of my part when typing this question. I'm able to get a connection using smbclient locally, but windows keeps telling me my access is denied.

Comment: Stephen, have you a firewall setup? There are four ports, which must be allowed - 445, 137, 138, 139.

Comment: Nope, don't have a firewall.